# How to prevent doubled timer in Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

### Description:

On a C# ASP.Net web application, we have implemented some timers to periodically run background tasks.  One of the timers occasionally seems to get "doubled" or more rarely "tripled".

The timer is set to run once every minute and seems to run properly for a while.  Eventually, however, it seems like a second timer gets started and calls the timed process a second time within the same time interval.  I've even seen a case where we had three processes running.

Since this process locks some database records and having a second (or third) process doing the same thing will cause a deadlock or timeout error on the database connection, we've implemented a mechanism to only allow one thread at a time to execute the database critical portion of the process code.  When the process takes longer than a minute to run, this mechanism successfully blocks the next run triggered by its own timer.  But the thread locking fails if the process is triggered by the second (or third) timer.

In our logs, I output both the Process ID and the Managed Thread ID, which lets me see which thread is starting, finishing, or erring out.  The strange thing, is that regardless of which timer instance kicked off the process, the Process ID is the same.

```
var processID = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
var thread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

**How do I prevent multiple instances of the timer?**

We have a web-farm with 2 servers behind a load balancer.  I've been assurred that the web-garden is set to only allow one instance of the app-pool on each server.  A web.config setting specifies which server will run the timed process.  The other server will not load the timer.

### Relevant Code:

On the Global.asax.cs

```
protected static WebTaskScheduler PersonGroupUpdateScheduler
{
    get;
    private set;
}

protected void StartSchedulers()
{
    using (var logger = new LogManager())
    {
        // ... other timers configured in similar fashion ...

        if (AppSetting.ContinuousPersonGroupUpdates)
        {
            // clear out-of-date person-group-updater lock
            logger.AppData.Remove("PersonGroupUpdater"); // database record to prevent interference with another process outside the web application.

            var currentServer = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName;
            if (currentServer.EqualsIngoreCase(AppSetting.ContinuousPersonGroupUpdateServer))
            {
                PersonGroupUpdateScheduler = new WebTaskScheduler() {
                    AutoReset = true,
                    Enabled = true,
                    Interval = AppSetting.ContinuousPersonGroupUpdateInterval.TotalMilliseconds,
                    SynchronizingObject = null,
                };
                PersonGroupUpdateScheduler.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DistributePersonGroupProcessing);
                PersonGroupUpdateScheduler.Start();
                HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(PersonGroupUpdateScheduler);
                logger.Save(Log.Types.Info, "Starting Continuous Person-Group Updating Timer.", "Web");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.Save(Log.Types.Info, string.Format("Person-Group Updating set to run on server {0}.", AppSetting.ContinuousPersonGroupUpdateServer), "Web");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Save(Log.Types.Info, "Person-Group Updating is turned off.", "Web");
        }
    }
}

private void DistributePersonGroupProcessing(object state, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // to start with a clean connection, create a new data context (part of default constructor)
    // with each call.
    using (var groupUpdater = new GroupManager())
    {
        groupUpdater.HttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        groupUpdater.ContinuousGroupUpdate(state, eventArgs);
    }
}
```

On a separate file, we have the WebTaskScheduler class which just wraps System.Timers.Timer and implements the IRegisteredObject interface so that IIS will recognize the triggered process as something it needs to deal with when shutting down.

```
public class WebTaskScheduler : Timer, IRegisteredObject
{
    private Action _action = null;
    public Action Action
    {
        get
        {
            return _action;
        }
        set
        {
            _action = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly WebTaskHost _webTaskHost = new WebTaskHost();

    public WebTaskScheduler()
    {
    }

    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        this.Stop();
        _action = null;
    }
}
```

Finally, the locking mechanism for the critical section of the code.

```
public void ContinuousGroupUpdate(object state, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var pgUpdateLock = PersonGroupUpdaterLock.Instance;

    try
    {
        if (0 == Interlocked.Exchange(ref pgUpdateLock.LockCounter, 1))
        {
            if (LogManager.AppData["GroupImporter"] == "Running")
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref pgUpdateLock.LockCounter, 0);
                LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Info, string.Format("Group Import is running, exiting Person-Group Updater.  Person-Group Update Signaled at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}.", eventArgs.SignalTime), "Person-Group Updater");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Info, string.Format("Continuous Person-Group Update is Starting.  Person-Group Update Signaled at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}.", eventArgs.SignalTime), "Person-Group Updater");
                LogManager.AppData["PersonGroupUpdater"] = "Running";

                // ... prep work is done here ...

                try
                {
                    // ... real work is done here ...

                    LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Info, "Continuous Person-Group Update is Complete", "Person-Group Updater");

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Data["Continuous Person-Group Update Activity"] = "Processing Groups";
                    ex.Data["Current Record when failure occurred"] = currentGroup ?? string.Empty;
                    LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Error, ex, "Person-Group Updater");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Error, ex, "Person-Group Updater");
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Exchange(ref pgUpdateLock.LockCounter, 0);
                LogManager.AppData.Remove("PersonGroupUpdater");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            // exit if another thread is already running this method
            LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Info, string.Format("Continuous Person-Group Update is already running, exiting Person-Group Updater.  Person-Group Update Signaled at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}.", eventArgs.SignalTime), "Person-Group Updater");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref pgUpdateLock.LockCounter, 0);
        LogManager.Save(Log.Types.Error, ex, "Person-Group Updater");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS can/will host multiple AppDomains under a worker process (w3wp). These AppDomains can't/don't/shouldn't really talk to each. It's IIS's responsibility to manage them.

I suspect what's happening is that you have multiple AppDomains loaded.

That said...just to be 100% sure...the timer is being started under Application_Start in your global.asax, correct? This will get executed once per AppDomain (not per HttpApplication, as it's name suggests).

You can check how many app domains are running for your process by using the `ApplicationManager's GetRunningApplications()` and get `GetAppDomain(string id)` methods.

In theory you could also do some inter-appdomain communication in there to make sure your process only starts once...but I'd strongly advise against it. In general, relying on scheduling from a web application is ill advised (because your code is meant to be ignorant of how IIS manages your application lifetime).

The preferred/recommended approach for scheduling is via a Windows Service.

Comment: Yes, the timer is initialized in the Application_Start event.

As for the advisibility of running periodic tasks from a web application, my lead asked me to code the process this way to simplify deployment and avoid the change-management and security hassles of deploying multiple commandline apps and windows services with our web app.  But from my research before asking this question, I'm wondering which hassle is worse: multiple apps or buggy timers.

Comment: I'll have to look at those two methods.  They might help my trouble-shooting, and let me programmatically determine how many app domains are running.

Comment: I would suggest to your lead that this design is really against intended usage and will just lead to more headaches as time goes on. I've tried this approach several times in the hopes of unifying and simplifying deployment and management....but it just doesn't work well.

Comment: I researched your comment about multiple AppDomains running in the same executable process, something I never before realized.  It turns out that IIS was sometimes spawning a second (or third) AppDomain.  Not having the political power to change the system to use a proper Windows Service, I modified the database and related code to send a locking signal, via the database, between the AppDomains.  
  
This has greatly reduced the problem, though I still get occasional deadlocks and timeouts on the database connections.  Still a couple errors per day is much better than numerous errors per hour.

Comment: Over time, the Lead who wanted it coded as part of the Web application moved on and another Lead came onto the project who recognized the problem and was willing to have it rewritten as a separate Windows Service. Things have worked much better since then.